# SharePoint Term Store Usage

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, taxonomy, term-store, cleanup

I've been tasked with cleaning up a Term Store.  The term store has six Term Groups each with a couple of Term Sets.  By the looks of things someone has "played about" with creating a taxonomy but it never really went anywhere.

1. What are the dangers, if any, of just deleting these?
2. Is there a PowerShell I can use to report on the usage of the term sets which have been created?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Quote from [article](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-properly-delete-and-hide-managed-metadata-terms-in-the-term-store/):

> When you delete a term from the Term Store it is permanently gone from
> the Term Store; however, if you had any documents or items tagged
> against it, they will not lose that Term (metadata) until the next
> time a user tries to tag a record (at which point the user will need
> to choose a new Term)

Refer to the following article about PowerShell script to find managed metadata column and all Managed Metadata Terms in use:(If you are using SharePoint online, remember to change Get-SPSite to Get SPOSite)

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/12/managed-metadata-columns-usage-report-using-powershell.html